# PHP post on same page

Tags: php, html

I have this code, and I want to send a message when the password = hello.
But the page shows immediadly the text: 'good pass' and 'bad pass'

What's wrong with this code?

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $wachtwoord = ($_POST['wachtwoord']);

    if ($wachtwoord = "hello")
    {
     ?><h1>Good pass</h1><?php;
    }

    else 

    if($wachtwoord != "hello")
    {
    ?><h1>Wrong pass.</h1><?php;
    }
} 

else 
{
?>
<center>
    <br><br><br><br>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Hello User, <br><br><hr>
            <b><a href="link0/">DirectAdmin</a><br><br>
            <a href="link1/">PHPMyAdmin</a></b><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <input name="wachtwoord" type="text" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" /></td></tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    <br><br>
    </center>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: use equalent operator  and the question is confusing its wrong pass not bad pass

Comment: change `if ($wachtwoord = "hello")` to `if ($wachtwoord == "hello")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're presently [**assigning**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) `if ($wachtwoord = "hello")` with a single equal sign `=`

Use two like this: `==` then do `if ($wachtwoord == "hello")` in order [**to compare**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

---

- [**Assignment operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) => `=`
- [**Comparison operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) => `==`

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the value `hello` to the variable `$wachtwoord` in this code

```
if ($wachtwoord = "hello")
                ^
    {
     ?><h1>Good pass</h1><?php;
    }
```

You have to use comparison operator(==) instead of using assignment operator (=). Change it to

```
if ($wachtwoord == "hello")
                 ^ 
    {
     ?><h1>Good pass</h1><?php;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Omg, I saved my file as HTML.

Sorry didn't code for a while :')

Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $wachtwoord = trim($_POST['wachtwoord']);

    if ($wachtwoord == "hello")
    {
      echo "Good Pass";
    }
    else 
    {
       echo "Bad Pass";
    }
} 
else 
{
?>
<center>
    <br><br><br><br>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Hello User, <br><br><hr>
            <b><a href="link0/">DirectAdmin</a><br><br>
            <a href="link1/">PHPMyAdmin</a></b><br>
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <input name="wachtwoord" type="text" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" /></td></tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    <br><br>
    </center>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
```

1 error and 1 suggesstion
ERROR:: == is used for comparison
SUGGESTION:: no need to use if condition in else part

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the = is not the problem. I changed it to == and he still doesn't work.

Comment: Tried it on phpfiddle.org and it is working fine. Please check if there is any other code on page which results in error.